# Python UDP Broadcast not working (not sending?)

Tags: python, sockets, udp, broadcast

I need to make a broadcast connection. I've 2 different software in python:

Client:

```python
broadSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
broadSock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST,1)
broadData = 8000
broadSock.sendto(bytes(broadData), ('<broadcast>' ,3333))
```

SERVER:

```python
broadSockListe = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
broadSockListe.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
broadSockListe.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
broadSockListe.bind(('',33333))
data, address = broadSockListe.recvfrom(1024)
```

I tried to listen the port of the server with the command: `sudo nc -l 3333` in the shell but nothing seems to arrive.

The Client run on windows and the server run on ubuntu.

Thank you

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem.

the ports were different :3333 vs 33333

and i changed the client last string to: 
    broadSock.sendto(bytes(broadData,"utf-8"), (('<broadcast>',3333))) in the old way it was sending a "thing" long 8000 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
host = '255.255.255.255'
port = 49160

# Discovery IP Conf Request
req = "\x54\x44"
crc = "\x3d\x73"
data = req+crc

# istanza il socket UDP
clie = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
clie.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
clie.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)


clie.sendto(data, (host, port))
print "tx:", data
clie.close()
```